# Antlr4 mutual left recursion error

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I prepared a grammar for a mini language I am creating, but I am getting a mutual left recursion error between `var` and `functioncall`

```
var
: NAME
| var '[' exp ']'
| var '.' var
| functioncall '.' var
;
functioncall
: NAME '(' (exp)? (',' exp)* ')'
| var '.' functioncall
| functioncall '.' functioncall
;
```

specifically at `var : functioncall '.' functioncall` and `functioncall : var '.' functioncall` which basically corresponds to `somefunction().var` and `instanceofClass.function()`.

Is there any way I can achieve this?

Edit : Grammar should also allow something like `var '=' exp` where var can be `instance.var` or `function().var`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Antlr 4 (and not before that) can handle both-side recursion in the same rule. So something like

```
expr: expr '+' expr | NUMBER
```

is valid.

So we can put another new rule to abstract either a var or a function call.

```
value
: var
| functioncall
| value '.' value
;

var
: NAME
| var '[' exp ']'
;

functioncall
: NAME '(' exp? (',' exp)* ')'
;
```

Not only the grammar is simpler to parse (to human readers), but now you have no mutual recursion.

*Note: untested.*

Comment: That grammar works for most cases except one. The language is also supposed to allow simple functioncall, i.e. a line containing simply functioncall. But its not supposed to allow a variable in single line, i.e. a line containing just `instance.function()` is valid but `variable` is not valid. Earlier I allowed this by not allowing  single variable in a line. Any way to achieve this?

Comment: @Nick_McCoy just improve the `value: var` rule to add the necessary syntax, like `value: var '.' value`.

Comment: that won't not allows something like var '=' exp. Also read my edited comment

Comment: @Nick_McCoy and your example won't either. I just answered the immediate problem posed by the question. It's easily adaptable to more complex grammars.

Comment: I see grammar can be easily extended using your snippet. Thanks a ton